# Sleep function in C (POSIX) breaks my program

Tags: c, fork, posix, sleep

This is my program code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void function() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(1) {
        int n = rand();
        printf("%d ", n);
        //sleep(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        function();
    }
}
```

With the sleep line commented out (as in the code above) the program works fine (i.e. it prints a bunch of random numbers too fast to even see if they are actually random), but if I remove the comment the program doesn't print anything and exits (not even the first time, before it gets to the sleep), even though it compiles without warnings or errors with or without the comment.

Comment: This surely won't compile without warnings if you don't even include required headers. You must provide a [mcve] for your question to be on-topic. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt With the exception of the headers, I think this is an excellent beginner question.

Comment: @AlbertoPerugini: what actual operating system do you use? POSIX is a complex specification (and many OSes are almost POSIX compliant, but not totally). For example [Debian](https://debian.org/) and [MacOSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Mac_OS_X) are almost POSIX compliant but differ in subtle ways

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I added the headers as suggested

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for the additional information about POSIX, I am using Ubuntu, adding the fflush to my code fixed it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch While it's true that it would be good mentioning Ubuntu, it's pretty hard for a beginner to understand that the terminal and general environment is relevant in this situation. Even I wouldn't. Well, I would, but that's because I know the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if I remove the comment the program doesn't print anything and exits

It does not print, but it does not really exit either. It will still be running a process in the background. And that process runs your infinite while loop.

Using your code in `p.c`:

```
$ gcc p.c 

$ ./a.out 

$ ps -A | grep a.out
 267282 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out

$ killall a.out

$ killall a.out
a.out: no process found
```

The problem is that `printf` does not really print. It only sends data to the output buffer. In order to force the output buffer to be printed, invoke `fflush(stdout)`

If you're not flushing, then you just rely on the behavior of the terminal you're using. It's very common for terminals to flush when you write a newline character to the output stream. That's one reason why it's preferable to use `printf("data\n")` instead of `printf("\ndata")`. See this question for more info: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/381711/283695

I'd suspect that if you just leave your program running, it will eventually print. It makes sense that it has a finite buffer and that it flushes when it gets full. But that's just an (educated) guess, and it depends on your terminal.

> it prints a bunch of random numbers too fast to even see if they are actually random

How do you see if a sequence of numbers is random? (Playing the devils advocate)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call [fflush(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) from time to time. See also [setvbuf(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) and [stdio(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) and [sysconf(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html).

I guess that if you coded:

```
while(1) {
    int n = rand();
    printf("%d ", n);
    if (n % 4 == 0)
       fflush(NULL);
    sleep(1);
}
```

The behavior of your program might be more user friendly. The buffer of `stdout` might have several dozens of kilobytes at least.

BTW,  I could be wrong. Check by reading a recent C draft standard (perhaps [n2176](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)).

At the very least, see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website then [syscalls(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [fork(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [sleep(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html).

You need to call [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or a similar function for every successful  [fork(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

If on Linux, read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and use both [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand the behavior of your program. With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) don't forget to compile it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get all warnings and debug info.

Consider also using the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).